# Create div class for images

Tags: html, css

I have a code which inserts images in my website footer. When I crop these pictures from the css, all the pictures on the website gets cropped. How do I solve this and insert a div class, if that now helps?

```
*{box-sizing: bortder-box}  /*lang-css*/

figure{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
img{margin: 0 10px; border-top: 2px solid red; border-bottom: 4px solid green}
img:first-child{width: 70px; height: 40px}
img:nth-child(2){width: 80px; height: 42px}
img:nth-child(3){width: 90px; height: 44px}
img:nth-child(4){width: 100px; height: 46px}
img:last-child{width: 120px; height: 48px}
```

---

```
<figure> <!--lang-html-->
  <img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3bbgs9CMAA5Cwi.jpg />
  <img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3bbgs9CMAA5Cwi.jpg />
  <img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3bbgs9CMAA5Cwi.jpg />
  <img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3bbgs9CMAA5Cwi.jpg />
  <img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3bbgs9CMAA5Cwi.jpg />
</figure>
```

Comment: There are many options. You could add a class to your `<figure>` or to your images themselves. Or select only images inside a figure: `figure img { ... }`.

Comment: When you say "code which inserts images", are you referring to javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to the html and css codes above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be more specific, you can add an id or a class to figure element and update the style like below. Adding an id of footer-images to the figure.

```
<figure id="footer-images">
<img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3bbgs9CMAA5Cwi.jpg />
<img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3bbgs9CMAA5Cwi.jpg />
<img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3bbgs9CMAA5Cwi.jpg />
<img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3bbgs9CMAA5Cwi.jpg />
<img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3bbgs9CMAA5Cwi.jpg />
</figure>

#footer-images {text-align: center;width: 100%;}
#footer-images img{margin: 0 10px; border-top: 2px solid red; border-bottom: 4px solid green}
#footer-images img:first-child{width: 70px; height: 40px}
#footer-images img:nth-child(2){width: 80px; height: 42px}
#footer-images img:nth-child(3){width: 90px; height: 44px}
#footer-images img:nth-child(4){width: 100px; height: 46px}
#footer-images img:last-child{width: 120px; height: 48px}
```

Comment: Your solution worked very good. Thank you. The #footer-images, does this ONLY edit the 5 images above or does it edit ALL images in the footer?

Comment: Could you please answer the sub question I had?

Comment: Since we are targeting the images of the figure tag with the id #footer-images, it will affect only the 5 images not any other image in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use specificity. Your css is targeting every image. Instead give the images a class or target images inside the figure likeso:

```
figure img{margin: 0 10px; border-top: 2px solid red; border-bottom: 4px solid green}
figure img:first-child{width: 70px; height: 40px}
figure img:nth-child(2){width: 80px; height: 42px}
figure img:nth-child(3){width: 90px; height: 44px}
figure img:nth-child(4){width: 100px; height: 46px}
figure img:last-child{width: 120px; height: 48px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should wrap img inside a div and use like this:

```
<div>
  <img src=https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B3bbgs9CMAA5Cwi.jpg />
</div>
```

css:

```
div{
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Now, images wouldn't be cropped but stretched.

If you even don't want to get stretched image then you should use background images and use background-size to cover:

```
<div class="bg1"></div>
```

css:

```
.bg1{
  background: url(...) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am totally lost right now. Could you please use one of my pictures as an example?Why would I want to add the URL in the CSS? I tried your solution also but it ruined my whole website...